# How to find average uncertainty for a set of results?

Tags: units, error-analysis

I have determined multiple values for the refractive index of a material, each with their own uncertainty.

If I find the average refractive index, how do I find its uncertainty? Would I find the standard deviation of the results of the refractive index, and then the error in the mean?

Comment: Ideally, a weighed average $x_{best}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}w_{i}X_{i}/\sum_{i=1}^{i=N}w_{i}$ where $x_{i}$ are the measurements, $\sigma_{i}$ are the uncertainties, and $w_{i}=1/\sigma^{2}_i$ are the weights. This assumes the measurements have a Gaussian distribution and is known as least squares method.